# how do i get the index of an object array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]How do i access the index of an objects array. 
[image]

I want to access the index of the items array in the form object

[image]

when i add a new item row. the items unit_price of the new row replace the already created rows.

**this is where the problem is originating**

```
 productSelected(product) {
     this.form.items['id'] = product.id;
     this.form.items['unit_price'] = product.price;
   }
```

i want assign the product.price to the form.items[index].unit_price

Comment: `form.items[0]` or you want to access all the array elements?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you need

Comment: @SunilLama i want to acess elements inside items array i have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is you want to fetch the index of item from the array, hope this help

```
form.items.forEach((item, index) => {
 console.log('item', item)
 console.log('index', index) // index of item
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.But my understanding i will post two type of answer:-

1) Get all the values from items array

```
   form.items.map((item)=> console.log(item));
```

2) Get Particuler index value:

```
   const findIndex = 0;
   form.items[findIndex];
```